# OCaml - Entering, Displaying, Validating Enumerated Types via stdin stdout

Tags: ocaml

enumerated type data:

```
type sex = | M | F | Undef;;
```

I'm wondering what's the preferred 'OCaml' way to enter and validate enumerated type data in a console program? I tried writing the program below and I'm sure I display the enum type correctly but I'm not sure if the validation in the while loop is correct. Basically I want the while loop contents to prompt the user for valid data for the enum type and display the value entered and then exit the loop or fail with a message and re-prompt the user for a valid data.

```
type sex = | M | F | Undef;;
type loop = | Yes | No;;

let match_sex s str =
    match s with
    | M -> print_endline "Male"
    | F -> print_endline "Female"
    | Undef ->
            Printf.fprintf stdout "You entered '%s'. Please enter single character(M\\F)\n" str;;

let looping = ref Yes;;

while !looping = Yes do
    let s = looping := No; print_string "Enter sex(M\\F)->"; read_line() in
    let c = Char.uppercase s.[0] in
    let ans =
        match (c, String.length s) with
        | 'M', 1 -> M
        | 'F', 1 -> F
        | _ -> looping := Yes; Undef in match_sex ans s
done;;
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd just do

```
type sex = M | F

let rec prompt () =
  let input =
    print_string "Enter sex(M\\F)->";
    read_line() in
  match String.uppercase input with
  | "M" -> print_endline "Male"; M
  | "F" -> print_endline "Female"; F
  | bad_input ->
    Printf.printf "You entered '%s'. Please enter single character(M\\F)\n" bad_input;
    prompt ()
```

A few points:

- prefer recursion over looping
- the extra function doesn't buy you much here so I get rid of it
- I removed the `Undef` sex since it will never be returned.
- `Printf.printf` over `Printf.fprintf stdout`

Comment: OK I see what you did and why you did it. I guess I'm having a hard time shaking off my imperative programming traits and thinking in a functional manner. Thank-you for your time and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
type sex = | Male | Female;;

let match_sex sx =
    match sx with
    | Male -> "Male"
    | Female -> "Female";;

let rec get_sex() =
    let str = print_string "Enter sex(M/F)->"; read_line() in
    match Char.uppercase (str.[0]), String.length str with
    | 'M', 1 -> Male
    | 'F', 1 -> Female
    | undef_sex ->
            Printf.fprintf stdout "Your entry '%s' was invalid. Please try again.\n" str; get_sex();;

Printf.fprintf stdout "Your sex is->%s\n" (match_sex (get_sex()));;
```

This is the solution I finally went with. Thanks rgrinberg